# Graduated symbol class error from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

For QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa, Win8

I am attempting to plot my data (about 50 points, imported CSV, converted to shapefile); as graduated by size, divided by natural breaks, 8 classes, link class boundaries, simple circle markers.

The problem is one point will not plot, unless the class is only that point (class 1):

```
1     .449872-.449872
2     .449872-.649973  
3     .648873-.749909
etc.
```

The point should plot with class 2 but does not. If I delete class 1, the point goes away.  I have tried tweaking the class values such that the value should be included in class 2 also, but no difference.

The circles are sized with the lowest values as the largest circles, if that matters. Additionally, sometimes the “show feature count” function gives the correct number of feature in the class but other times, it only lists zeros, (not a separate question, maybe a related symptom).